# How to get a user token from Logonuser for a user account with no password?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

How can you get a user token from Logonuser for a user account with no password?

In particular Logonuser will fail for accounts that do not have passwords.
You can validate an account by checking for a blank password + checking for GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCOUNT_RESTRICTION.

But I need to actually get a token returned, so I need this function to succeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will fail if the registry setting LimitBlankPasswordUse is enabled, which it is by default. In order to disable this change the LimitBlankPasswordUse value under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa to zero. Or change the group policy setting under Security Options.

Be aware that this creates a security hole since it allows remote logons for accounts with null passwords.

Comment: When LimitBlankPasswordUse is set you are still allowed to create accounts with blank passwords but they are limited to local console logon.

Comment: Can I get such a user token? Local console is fine.

Comment: By local console I mean physically logging in at the computer. You could retrieve the token once someone had physically logged in but there is no way to do the logon programmatically.

Comment: Does this mean windows scheduler is broken if there is an account with no password?

Comment: I just verified and windows gives the error about account restriction blank password.  So it's true you can't use windows task scheduler with a blank password.